# Button press ajax request overclick javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a button in my HTML form where I have tied an onlick event. The button adds values to an input field. Every time the button is clicked I send a post request to my Nodejs server to store up to data input value in mysql database. It is very important that the input value that is stored is up to date.

```
     $('.wrapper').on('change','.fireChange',function(e){
     addIndividualParts()
})

    $('.wrapper').on('click','.btnfireChange',function(e){
         addIndividualParts()
    })

    function addIndividualParts() {
        var studentNumber = $('input[name="studentNumber[]"]').map(function() {
            return this.value
        }).get()


        var quantity = $('input[name="quantity[]"]').map(function() {
            return this.value
        }).get()




        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/orderDetails",
            data: {
                studentNumber: studentNumber,
                quantity: quantity,
                orderID: $('#orderID').html(),
                ajaxSubmit: true //I am setting this so that in the backend I can distinguish between orderDetails form submisssion vs submitting using jquery where I do not want to redirect
            }
        });
    }
```

The probelm that I have realized is that someone can spam that add button and overload the server. I am listening to `change` event in the input box which only fires when I change the value manually an move out of the input box. However, if I increment using an add button and javascript that event does not fire. Therefore, I have a separate event to track add button.

What would be the best way to keep track of up to date info in my form but also not overload the server?

Comment: You can disable the button after it's been clicked.

Comment: The add button is supposed to increment the integer value in the input box so the user should be able to click multiple times. I was just wandering if we could get the last value

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you so much for showing me what to search for. I implemented a solution using debounce that I will post below

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution using debounce. This code waits for 5 seconds before sending a post request and resets each time someone clicks a button which allows me to make only 1 API call at max in a 5 second period at the same time allowing me to send the latest value

```
// Credit David Walsh (https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.

    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;

        // This is the function that is actually executed when
        // the DOM event is triggered.
        return function executedFunction() {
          // Store the context of this and any
          // parameters passed to executedFunction
          var context = this;
          var args = arguments;

          // The function to be called after 
          // the debounce time has elapsed
          var later = function() {
            // null timeout to indicate the debounce ended
            timeout = null;

            // Call function now if you did not on the leading end
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
          };

          // Determine if you should call the function
          // on the leading or trail end
          var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

          // This will reset the waiting every function execution.
          // This is the step that prevents the function from
          // being executed because it will never reach the 
          // inside of the previous setTimeout  
          clearTimeout(timeout);

          // Restart the debounce waiting period.
          // setTimeout returns a truthy value (it differs in web vs node)
          timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

          // Call immediately if you're dong a leading
          // end execution
          if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
      };


      var returnedFunction = debounce(function() {
        addIndividualParts()
      }, 3000);




    $('.fieldsWrapper').on('change','.fireChange',function(e){
         returnedFunction()
    })



    $('.fieldsWrapper').on('click','.btnfireChange',function(e){
        returnedFunction()
    })
```